# How to create IIS-website from powershell in order to host .net core 2.0 app

Tags: powershell, iis, .net-core

**Expected Result**:

IIS hosts my app correctly, and when I navigate to the url of my app (e.g: blabla/swagger) I see the swagger UI describing my app

**Problem**:

When I try to navigate to my app it says:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

**Information**

I built an app in .net core 2.0 and I am able to make it run through visual studio, being hosted by Kestrel. 
However I need to deploy this app to different servers and since Kestrel doesn't support host names, I need to make it being hosted in IIS . When I make it run through Kestrel I am able to access it correctly and by navigating to the url/swagger address, I am able to see the correct swagger page that describes the app.
My app is being *published* from visual studio. Which means in its published folder there are all the dlls that the app needs. It's being published as a framework dependent app, not a standalone one, but this shouldn't matter.

**How to replicate the problem**

Since I need this one day to be hosted in IIS inside a Docker container, I am trying to make it being hosted in IIS with powershell scripts. What I did to make it being hosted in IIS is:

```
New-Website -Name 'myTestApp' -force -Port 8080 -PhysicalPath
'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Docker\PublishOutput' -ApplicationPool 'MyAppPoolTest'
```

Where *C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Docker\PublishOutput* is the path to the published folder where Visual Studio publishes the app. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is the web.config generated by Visual studio when publishing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Friss.CaseApi.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 313d542d-7676-4440-ae1b-22c6071f4309-->
```

And the error page is:

[image]

Error 2:

[image]

Comment: @mjwills edited with the web.config

Comment: The whole error page is important, as it contains other information needed. Something like https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4 might get you started.

Comment: @LexLi uploaded the full error page

Comment: As the Error Code is 0x80070005 and Config Error is "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions", you should grant IIS_IUSRS permissions on the PublishOutput folder. It is a typical mistake to host file contents from a user's folder (C:\Users\someone) on IIS and forget to grant such permissions.

Comment: That indeed was the error.. I will open another ticket with exactly the same setup question because right after solving this error I am facing another one I can't explain. Thanks a lot for your help @LexLi :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Error Code is `0x80070005` and Config Error is "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions", you should grant `IIS_IUSRS` permissions on the `PublishOutput` folder.

It is a typical mistake to host file contents from a user's folder (`C:\Users\someone`) on IIS and forget to grant such permissions.

For other typical ASP.NET Core on IIS issues, read [my blog post](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4).

Comment: I edited the question.. the error that is coming now is not that far from the one of before, that's why I edited it and uploaded a screenshot. Still the same kind of error page but no info about it this time

Comment: @Tarta check the blog post I listed in the comment earlier. It talks about that.